# Print glossary description if entry was not seen

Tags: glossaries

I have a glossary with short and long titles for bibliography items.
My goal is the following: when an entry occurs first, I want to print to glossary description [THIS is the main question!]. If an entry occurs twice in a row, in the second case I want to print Ibid. instead of its title [this is done]. Otherwise I want to print the glossary name for the entry. I tried list handling and other conditionals, but wasn't succesful. I'd appreciate your help.

As I have a rather large document with more than 500 references, I'd like to keep the codes already done, but I'm open to any solution.

Here is the code which I already have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\def\mygls{empty}
\def\myftncounter{0}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\footcite}{m}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\mygls}{#1}}{%
        \ifthenelse{%
            \equal{\myftncounter}{\thefootnote}%
            }{%
            \edef\thisgls{Ibid}%
            }{%
            \edef\thisgls{\gls{#1}}%
            }%
    }{%
        \edef\thisgls{\gls{#1}}%
        \xdef\mygls{#1}%
    }%
    \footnote{\thisgls}%
    \xdef\myftncounter{\thefootnote}%   
}

\newglossaryentry{G1}{name={short1},description={long1}}
\newglossaryentry{G2}{name={short2},description={long2}}

\begin{document}
    
Lorem\footcite{G1} ipsum\footcite{G1} dolor\footcite{G2} sit\footcite{G1} amet.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you use glossary for this? Why not biblatex? And if has to be glossary, why don't you use its tools? It has tests if an entry has already been seen.

Comment: x-post https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=5880